# Tooltip going out of the screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular

I have so many tooltip inside a container but when i click on right-most and the left-most tooltip  the modal open below them go out of the screen.

I have already tried applying media query depending on the screen size making them left or right but there can be any tooltip.

so can anyone suggest any solution on how to check which tooltip modal is going out of the screen and align left or right according to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely check the offset of an element as

```
var x = $("p").offset();
alert("Top: " + x.top + " Left: " + x.left);
```

and the height and width of the viewport as

```
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
```

Similarly you can get the dimensions of the tooltip ( I hope it is a custom tooltip)

Rest is simple mathematics to check whether the it goes out of the viewport or not and adjust your styles accordingly.